# Correct way to define a function in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I'm trying out a few tutorials.
I wrote this script:

```
lucky::(Integral a)=> a-> String
lucky 7 = "LUCKY NUMBER 7"
lucky x = "Bad luck"
```

I saved this as lucky.hs and ran it in the interpreter and it works fine.

But I am unsure about function definitions. It seems from the little I have read that I could equally define the function lucky as follows (function name is lucky2):

```
lucky2::(Integral a)=> a-> String
lucky2 x=(if x== 7 then "LUCKY NUMBER 7" else "Bad luck")
```

Both seem to work equally well. Clearly function *lucky* is clearer to read but is the *lucky2* a correct way to write a function?

Comment: As far as I know, they're equal in meaning but the first one looks nicer and is the preferred way of doing it in Haskell. I'll not post this as an answer as I'm not a Haskell adept and may be wrong.

Comment: By the way, you do not need brackets: `lucky2 x= if x== 7 then "LUCKY NUMBER 7" else "Bad luck"`

Comment: Also you can write the type equally as `lucky :: Integral -> String`. The naming stuff to the left of `=>` is just for case you need the same type twice.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? If it works, then iit is clearly "correct" syntax. Are you asking if "if" statements are *idiomatic*?

Comment: @Thomas: This is not true. Integral is a typeclass, not a type.

Comment: @sdcvv Ah right, I was thinking Integer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

They are both correct. Arguably, the first one is more idiomatic Haskell because it uses its very important feature called **pattern matching**. In this form, it would usually be written as:

```
lucky::(Integral a)=> a-> String
lucky 7 = "LUCKY NUMBER 7"
lucky _ = "Bad luck"
```

The underscore signifies the fact that you are ignoring the exact form (value) of your parameter. You only care that it is different than `7`, which was the pattern captured by your previous declaration.

---

The importance of pattern matching is best illustrated by function that operates on more complicated data, such as lists. If you were to write a function that computes a length of list, for example, you would likely start by providing a variant for empty lists:

```
len [] = 0
```

The `[]` clause is a pattern, which is set to match empty lists. Empty lists obviously have length of 0, so that's what we are having our function return.

The other part of `len` would be the following:

```
len (x:xs) = 1 + len xs
```

Here, you are matching on the pattern `(x:xs)`. Colon `:` is the so-called **cons operator**: it is appending a value to list. An expression `x:xs` is therefore a pattern which matches some element (`x`) being appended to some list (`xs`). As a whole, it matches a list which has at least one element, since `xs` can also be an empty list (`[]`).

This second definition of `len` is also pretty straightforward. You compute the length of remaining list (`len xs`) and at 1 to it, which corresponds to the first element (`x`).

(The usual way to write the above definition would be:

```
len (_:xs) = 1 + len xs
```

which again signifies that you do not care what the first element is, only that it exists).

Comment: Unfortunately, you demonstrate a bad way for computing list lengths.

Comment: Ingo, wut? Even the std. library does it this way: [genericLength](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/src/Data-List.html#genericLength). You can do an optimisation for `Int`s and some other types, sure (see `strictGenericLength`), but it does not even change the asymptotic time requirements.

Answer (score 7):

A 3rd way to write this would be using guards:

```
lucky n
    | n == 7    = "lucky"
    | otherwise = "unlucky"
```

There is no reason to be confused about that. There is always more than 1 way to do it. Note that this would be true even if there were no pattern matching or guards and you *had* to use the `if`.

All of the forms we've covered so far use so-called *syntactic sugar* provided by Haskell. Pattern guards are transformed to ordinary case expressions, as well as multiple function clauses and if expressions. Hence the most low-level, unsugared way to write this would be perhaps:

```
lucky n = case n of
     7 -> "lucky"
     _ -> "unlucky"
```

While it is good that you check for idiomatic ways I'd recommend to a beginner that he uses whatever works for him best, whatever he understands best. For example, if one does (not yet) understand points free style, there is no reason to force it. It will come to you sooner or later.